# Migrate from WebSphere to Tomcat 7, No unique bean of type [com.m.g.tenancy.ITenantPlaceholderResolver] is defined: expected single bean but found 0

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, websphere

I'm relatively new to Spring and Tomcat, currently attempting to migrate a web application from WebSphere to Tomcat 7. I'm running into many issues along the way and tackling them one by one.  Right now I'm looking at this error and I am stumped:

> 15:05:15.362 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   c.m.g.t.TenantDispatcherServlet - Could not add tenant
>   DC.HKG.SALES.VNM, details
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [com.m.gsp.tenancy.ITenantPlaceholderResolver] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 0:

This application worked previously in WebSphere and I only made one change to the XML files, my tenant-context.xml contained this line:

```
<import resource="classpath:/WEB-INF/core-context.xml" />
```

core-context.xml could not be found, so I changed it to:

```
<import resource="classpath*:WEB-INF/core-context.xml" />
```

And now it appears that core-context.xml can be found but I get the above `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. Any ideas?

Comment: I would be surprised even that even worked as `/WEB-INF` isn't part of the class path...

Comment: If you want migrate from WebSphere, maybe you should consider [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/). It is as lightweight as Tomcat, but Java EE web profile compliant, not just simple web container. If your application have used features provided by container, you will have tons of issues while migrating to Tomcat.

Comment: Im want to go open source with this project, trying to get away from IBM products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M. Deinum's comment pointed me in the right direction, I ended up creating an enviornment variable that pointed to the `WEB-INF` directory.

In Eclipse this can be accomplished by double-clicking the Tomcat server in your servers view, clicking 'open launch conifguration', and then adding the variable in the 'Enviornment' tab.  My variable was set up like so:

`webInfDir = file:/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/M-GSP-Web/WEB-INF`

then I referenced that variable in place of the classpath

`<import resource="${webInfDir}/core-context.xml" />`

Thanks for your input, everyone.